# Merge lambda layers in cdk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-lambda-layers

I've noticed in the console you are able to merge lambda layers (see picture below), I was wondering if there is anyway to do this via the cdk? The reason I would want to do this would be to combine 1-20 lambda layers via a merge so we don't hit the uper limit of layers we can use on a function.
[image]

This is how we are currently adding layers

```py
layer1:ILayerVersion = aws_lambda.LayerVersion.from_layer_version_arn(....)
layer2:ILayerVersion = aws_lambda.LayerVersion.from_layer_version_arn(....)

lambda_function = aws_lambda.Function(..., layers = [layer1, layer2])
```

would like to do something like what we have below just to combine all the layers in one so I don't hit the lambda layer max

```py
layer1:ILayerVersion = aws_lambda.LayerVersion.from_layer_version_arn(....)
layer2:ILayerVersion = aws_lambda.LayerVersion.from_layer_version_arn(....)
combined_layer:ILayerVersion = aws_lambda.LayerVersion.combine(layer1,layer2) #psuedo code not real
lambda_function = aws_lambda.Function(..., layers = [combined_layer])
```

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding what is happening in the console. Layers are always merged together regardless of how you deploy them. That's part of the process when it mounts the contents to /opt in your execution environment. This simply controls the order of the merge process. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-layers.html#invocation-layers-accessing

Comment: better write this kind of answer as a comment